# Splitting a text file where the information are separated in different lines

Tags: file, text, split

So, I have a text file where the information are separated by the enter key (I don't know how to explain, I will paste the code and some stuff).

```
cha-cha
Fruzsina
Ede
salsa
Szilvia
Imre
```

Here's how the text file looks like, and I need to split it into three parts, the first being the type of the dance, and then dancer 1 and dancer 2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace tanciskola
{
    struct tanc
    {
        public string tancnev;
        public string tancos1;
        public string tancos2;
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region 1.feladat
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("tancrend.txt");
            tanc[] tanc = new tanc[140];
            string[] elv;
            int i = 0;
            while (sr.Peek() != 0)
            {
                elv = sr.ReadLine().Split('I don't know what goes here');
                tanc[i].tancnev = elv[0];
                tanc[i].tancos1 = elv[1];
                tanc[i].tancos2 = elv[2];
                i++;
            }
            #endregion
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I tried to solve it, although I don't really get how I should do it. The task is would be to display the first dance and the last dance, but for that I need to split it somehow.

Comment: So pattern is dance,dancer1,dancer2 and then repeat each 3 line set? You don't need to split at all if that is the case. Just get all lines and loop over them.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comments, you seem to have a text file where each item is on a new line, and a set of 3 lines constitutes a single 'record'. In that case, you can simply read all the lines of the file, and then create your records, like so:

```
var v = File.ReadLines("file path");

        tancr[] tanc = new tancr[140];

        for (int i = 0; i < v.Count(); i += 3)
        {                
            tanc[i/3].tancnev= v.ElementAt(i);
            tanc[i/3].tancos1 = v.ElementAt(i + 1);
            tanc[i/3].tancos2 = v.ElementAt(i + 2);
        }
```

Note: `ReadLines()` is better when the file size is large. If your file is small, you could use `ReadAllLines()` instead.

Comment: I left my answer for posterity, but this would be the solution I'd suggest. Especially if the file is larger.

Comment: Okay, this almost works. How do I display them though? If I write Console.WriteLine("{0}", tanc[0].tancnev); It doesn't give me the first dance. How does this work exactly?

Comment: What does it display then? The loop reads from the collection of lines read from file, assigns to the variable, and then increments counter by 3 to read the next set of 3 lines i.e. next record

Comment: Edited answer. Should be `i/3` to advance to next array index. `i%3` will always be 0. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

To split by the "enter character" you can use Environment.NewLine in .NET:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx

```
elv = sr.ReadAllText().Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

This constant will contain the sequence that is specific to your OS (I'm guessing Windows).

You should be aware that the characters used for newlines is different for Windows vs. Linux/Unix. So in the rare event that someone edits your file on a different OS, you can run into problems.

On Windows, newline is a two character sequence: carriage-return + line-feed (ASCII 13 + 10). On Linux it is just line-feed. So if you wanted to be extra clever, you could first check for CRLF and if you only get one element back from Split() then try just LF.

Comment: It gives me two errors.

The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'

I don't know why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Alright, I did ('\r','\n'), it seems to accept it. The new error is with the line tanc[i].tancos1 = elv[1]; IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled. Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected the syntax in my answer below. String.Split() actually makes it a little more complicated than VB.NET's Split() where you can pass in a string.By default, String.Split is expecting an array of different single-character separators. What we want is one single multi-character (i.e. string) separator, which is what that more complicated overload gives us.

Comment: Still gives me the same error. There is probably another way I haven't considered, because this should be an easy task.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's late because I spaced on the obvious issue. You are reading in from the file *one line at a time*, so that means you will never have newlines in your string. That is why you get the IndexOutOfRange exception. I've tweaked the answer to read all text at once, but other poster is right that processing line by line doesn't require a split.